# I am loosing vertical space befor and after minipage/parbox/vbox within a list

Tags: spacing, lists

I have a two column list. Some of the items are supposed to be grouped by a huge brace so I am trying to use `minipage` or `parbox` or `vbox` to group them, however I am loosing the vertical space between lines before and after the grouped items:

[image]

How can I make sure that the vertical spacing stays consistent?

Here is my [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/mzkgtjkvxkvv):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{calc}

\tolerance=1000
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\protect\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{twocolumnitemize}[1]
 {%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[#1]
  \raggedcolumns\RaggedRight
  \begin{itemize}
 }
 {%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
 }


\begin{document}

\begin{twocolumnitemize}{This is from what I can remember, so there may be some mistakes:}
  \tightlist
\item Sai (sometimes)
\item Nunchukas (sometimes)
\item Ninjato (sometimes)
\item Shuriken (15)
\item Bushido Blade (higher levels)
  %\begin{minipage}[c]{\columnwidth}
  \parbox[c]{\columnwidth}{%
  \item Ninja Cowl \protect\tikzmark{xen-xheng-topbrace}
  \item Ninja Garb (U)
  \item Ninja Garb (L)
  \item Tabi Boots \tikzmark{xen-xheng-bottombrace}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,black]
      let \p1=(xen-xheng-topbrace), \p2=(xen-xheng-bottombrace) in
      ({max(\x1,\x2)+2em}, {\y1+0.8em}) -- node[right=0.6em] {\parbox{5em}{may not have all at once}} ({max(\x1,\x2)+2em}, {\y2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  %\end{minipage}
\item Tosei-do (U) (higher levels)
\item Tosei-do (L) (higher levels)
\end{twocolumnitemize}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 1**

If I do not use any kind of grouping for the 4 items, I will get something like this:

[image: broken]

Comment: `\item` should always be directly in a list, the fact that `\parbox[c]{\columnwidth}{%
  \item` doesn't stop with an error is just due to lax error checking in latex, you could add the brace without needing to box (eg get tikz to record the first and last line)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK. However, I need something to keep the 4 items together. The `\tikzmark` will work even if they are not together but the brace will be rendered wrongly.